# Why does my packaged WinForms App take 60 seconds to start?

Tags: desktop-bridge, msix

The app works fine after it starts but it consistently takes about 60 seconds + high CPU before my code starts executing. When I run the app from Visual Studio or via the old click once install it starts instantly.

The .msix file is about 130 MB. The app has a dependency on the Crystal Reports runtime. I used the MSIX Packaging Tool to create the package for the Crystal runtime, then I added my app to that package.

I'm stumped.

Comment: Oddly enough on end users machines the app starts right up. I think because I have the Crystal Developer runtime installed that the "file system merge" is what is causing the slow start on my machine.  Hope this helps someone else down the road.